# jQuery Deferred - How to wait or delay for .animate function to finish before .done() is executed?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-deferred

I have a series of deferred actions that take place as part of a $.when() .done()

```
        $.when(
          $activeHighlight.removeClass('active'),
          $nextHighlight.addClass('active'),
          $nextHighlight.fadeIn(250),
          scrollToActiveHighlightConfirmationSlide(0),
        ).done(
          lazyloadHighlightConfirmationHighlights.load($nextHighlightImage[0])
        );
```

This works just fine! But whenever I try to preface that series of events with a function that calls an animation, it never seems to 'wait' for the animation to finish before proceeding.

Here's how I've tried structuring it:

```
        function slideLeft() {
          $activeHighlightImage.animate(
            {
              left: -$activeHighlightImage.width(),
              opacity: "0",
            }, 200);
        }

        $.when(
          slideLeft()
        ).done(
          $activeHighlight.hide(),
          $.when(
            $activeHighlight.removeClass('active'),
            $nextHighlight.addClass('active'),
            $nextHighlight.fadeIn(250),
            scrollToActiveHighlightConfirmationSlide(0),
          ).done(
            lazyloadHighlightConfirmationHighlights.load($nextHighlightImage[0])
          ),
        )
```

I can run the animation in isolation and it works just fine, so I must be missing something when it comes to adding it as a deferred event.

Ideally, it would go something like this...

1. slideLeft, which takes 200ms
2. (wait for 200ms, while the above animation completes)
3. $activeHighlight.hide()
4. Immediately prep to show the new highlight by completing the .when() functions
5. Then, on .done(), call the lazyloader to load in the new highlight's image.

Getting something like number 2 to occur is where I'm currently having trouble...

Any ideas?

Comment: `return $activeHighlightImage.animate(...).promise()` (the .promise() may not even be needed)

Comment: Hi @KevinB! Thanks for chiming in. Unfortunately, it still doesn't work... It seems like I need a way to delay the initial progression through the .done() functions. Something  akin to `slideLeft().delay(200)` but that doesn't quite do what I'm after either...

Answer (score 0):

From other great conversations I've read, my impression is that jQuery promises don't play well with the sort of delays or waiting I'm looking for. And to be honest, the solutions they put forward were a bit over my head at this point in time.

Then I realized...

What I was after was not so much a promise delay, but rather a way to somehow SHOW a "slideLeft()" animation.

And that's when it hit me! Instead of trying to use jQuery's excellent .animate() function, I created separate image classes with various transform 3d matrices.

This allowed me to initially start subsequent highlight images off to the right and then, as part of the original .done() action, 'center' the image, thereby creating the effect I was after.

Here's the scss I used

```
        -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease;
        -moz-transition: all 400ms ease;
        -o-transition: all 400ms ease;
        transition: all 400ms ease;

        &.out-right {
          transform: matrix3d(
            1,0,0,0,
            0,1,0,0,
            0,0,1,0,
            800,0,0,1
          );
        }

        &.active {
          transform: matrix3d(
            1,0,0,0,
            0,1,0,0,
            0,0,1,0,
            0,0,0,1
          );
        }

        &.out-left {
          transform: matrix3d(
            1,0,0,0,
            0,1,0,0,
            0,0,1,0,
            -800,0,0,1
          );
        }
```

Here's how I changed the original $.when .done

```
        $.when(
          $activeHighlight.removeClass('active'),
          $nextHighlight.addClass('active'),
          $nextHighlight.fadeIn(250),
          scrollToActiveHighlightConfirmationSlide(0),
        ).done(
          lazyloadHighlightConfirmationHighlights.load($nextHighlightImage[0]),
          $nextHighlightImage.addClass('active'),
        );
```

And then, in the associated view, I merely had to step up the initial class structure for the images. It looked something like this

```
 <div class="highlight">
    <%= image_tag tag.images.first.file_url(:speck),
      class: "active",
      ...
    %>
  </div>

  <% tag.images.drop(1).each do |image| %>
    <div class="highlight">
      <%= image_tag image.file_url(:speck),
        class: "out-right",
        ...
      %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

So if anyone else is looking for a way to incorporate animations within the a jQuery promise and is running into the same issues I was, maybe coming at it from a different angle will give the result you're after?

PS: I didn't show how I 'reset' the image class states as I cycled through them, but if you need that posted, feel free to request it and I'll share what I came up with.